# How to take the DidFinishProcessingPhoto(from IAVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate) responsibility out of the ViewController

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to create a single responsibility straight forward testable Ios based Class  that does one thin and one thing only: Start session(previewing it to the injected UIView) and handle saving photo to Photo Library.

I have the classes and interface below. I have a problem that I can't see how to solve: I can't make CapturingCamera implement IAVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate because the DidFinishProcessingPhoto method is not triggered... the only way it can get called if I make the calling UIViewController implement IAVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate and call DidFinishProcessingPhoto

But I don't like that because I would like to encapsulate it in the CapturingCamera class.

I'm not sure what I am missing here or if this is a xamarin limitation (I hope the problem is with me)

please share your knowledge, thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using AVFoundation;
using CoreMedia;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;

namespace IosCameraLibrary2017
{
    public interface ICapturingCamera
    {
        AVCaptureSession CaptureSession { get; }
        AVCaptureDevice CaptureDevice { get; }
        AVCaptureDeviceInput CaptureDeviceInput { get; }
        AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer PreviewLayer { get; }
        UIView View { get; }
        IAVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate CaptureDelegate { get; }
        IntPtr Handle { get; }

        AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer GetWorkingPreview();
        void TakePicture();

        void Dispose();
    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using AVFoundation;
using CoreFoundation;
using CoreMedia;
using CoreVideo;
using Foundation;
using Photos;
using UIKit;

namespace IosCameraLibrary2017
{
    public class CapturingCamera : ICapturingCamera
    {
        public AVCaptureSession CaptureSession { get; private set; }
        public AVCaptureDevice CaptureDevice { get; private set; }
        public AVCaptureDeviceInput CaptureDeviceInput { get; private set; }
        public AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer PreviewLayer { get; private set; }
        public UIView View { get; private set; }
        public IAVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate CaptureDelegate { get; private set; }

        public CapturingCamera(UIView view, IAVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate captureDelegate)
        {
            CaptureSession = new AVCaptureSession();
            CaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.GetDefaultDevice(AVMediaType.Video);
            CaptureDeviceInput = AVCaptureDeviceInput.FromDevice(CaptureDevice);
            View = view;
            CaptureDelegate = captureDelegate;
        }

        public AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer GetWorkingPreview()
        {
            CaptureSession.AddInput(CaptureDeviceInput);
            CaptureSession.StartRunning();
            PreviewLayer = new AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(CaptureSession);
            PreviewLayer.Frame = View.Bounds;
            View.Layer.AddSublayer(PreviewLayer);
            return PreviewLayer;
        }

        public void TakePicture()
        {
            var output = new AVCapturePhotoOutput();
            CaptureSession.AddOutput(output);
            var settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings.Create();
            var previewPixelType = settings.AvailablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.First();

            var keys = new[]
            {
                new NSString("kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey"),
                new NSString("kCVPixelBufferWidthKey"),
                new NSString("kCVPixelBufferHeightKey"),
            };

            var objects = new NSObject[]
            {
                // don't have to be strings... can be any NSObject.
                previewPixelType,
                new NSString("160"),
                new NSString("160")
            };

            var dicionary = new NSDictionary<NSString, NSObject>(keys, objects);

            //settings.PreviewPhotoFormat = dicionary;
            settings.PreviewPhotoFormat = new NSDictionary<NSString, NSObject>(CVPixelBuffer.PixelFormatTypeKey, settings.AvailablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes[0]);

            output.CapturePhoto(settings, CaptureDelegate);
        }

        public IntPtr Handle { get; }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            //
        }
    }
}


using System;
using System.Linq;
using AVFoundation;
using CoreMedia;
using CoreVideo;
using Foundation;
using IosCameraLibrary2017;
using Photos;
using UIKit;

namespace XamarinIosTry2
{
    public partial class ViewController : UIViewController, IAVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate
    {
        private ICapturingCamera cameraManager;

        public ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle){}

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            if (!AppDelegate.IsDesignTime)
            {
                cameraManager = new CapturingCamera(viewCamera,this);
                cameraManager.GetWorkingPreview();
            }
        }

        [Export(
            "captureOutput:didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer:previewPhotoSampleBuffer:resolvedSettings:bracketSettings:error:")]
        public void DidFinishProcessingPhoto(AVCapturePhotoOutput captureOutput,
            CMSampleBuffer photoSampleBuffer, CMSampleBuffer previewPhotoSampleBuffer,
            AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings resolvedSettings, AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings bracketSettings,
            NSError error)
        {
            if (photoSampleBuffer == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error occurred while capturing photo: {error}");
                return;
            }

            NSData imageData = AVCapturePhotoOutput.GetJpegPhotoDataRepresentation(photoSampleBuffer, previewPhotoSampleBuffer);
            PHPhotoLibrary.RequestAuthorization(status =>
            {
                if (status == PHAuthorizationStatus.Authorized)
                {
                    PHPhotoLibrary.SharedPhotoLibrary.PerformChanges(() =>
                    {
                        PHAssetCreationRequest.CreationRequestForAsset().AddResource(PHAssetResourceType.Photo, imageData, null);
                    }, (success, err) =>
                    {
                        if (!success)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Error occurred while saving photo to photo library: {err}");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Photo was saved to photo library");
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Not authorized to save photo");
                }
            });
        }

        partial void BtnAction_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
        {
            cameraManager.TakePicture();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclassing `AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate` should work fine:

```
public class CapturingCamera : AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate, ICapturingCamera
{
    // Implement your ICapturingCamera interface methods...

    public override void DidFinishProcessingPhoto(AVCapturePhotoOutput output, AVCapturePhoto photo, NSError error)
    {
       ~~~
    }
}
```

Then in your call AVCapturePhotoOutput.CapturePhoto inside your `CapturingCamera` instance pass it `this` for the delegate.